# Executing different functions on the running server in python

Tags: python

I am trying to parse a HTML document in it by beautifulSoup.

I have 2 separate sections in the document.

Below is my code.

```
import os
import json
import requests
import cherrypy
import ConfigParser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Server():

    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):

        return "Seems Like You're Lost :D"


    @cherrypy.expose
    def recharge_list(self,carrier, state):
        details_array=[]
        small_details_array=[]
        price_cell_array=[]
        lst = []
        url = "link/{}/{}".format(carrier,state)
        try:
            if self.t_arr.get(url) is not None:
                return json.dumps({'data': self.t_arr[url]})
        except AttributeError:
            self.t_arr = {}
        r  = requests.get(url)
        data = r.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data,"html.parser")
        table = soup.find('table',{'class':'table'})
        s=""
        detailtext = table.findAll('div',{'class':'detailtext'})


        for det in detailtext:
            details_array.append(det.text)

        smalldetails = table.findAll('div',{'style':'padding-top:5px'})

        for smallDet in smalldetails:
            small_details_array.append(smallDet.text);


        price_cells = table.findAll('td', {'class': 'pricecell'})
        for price_cell in price_cells:
            price_cell_array.append(price_cell.text)

        for i in range(len(details_array)):
            d_arr = {}
            d_arr['detail']=details_array[i]
            temp = small_details_array[i].split('\n')
            d_arr['talktime'] = temp[1] 
            d_arr['keyword']=temp[3]
            tempnew = price_cell_array[i].split('\n')
            d_arr['price'] = tempnew[1]
            d_arr['validity'] = tempnew[3]
            # global list
            lst.append(d_arr)
        self.t_arr[url] = lst
        return json.dumps({'data': self.t_arr[url]})

    @cherrypy.expose
    def sms_list(self,carrier, state):
        details_array=[]
        price_cell_array=[]
        lst = []
        url = "link/{}/{}".format(carrier,state)
        try:
            if self.t_arr.get(url) is not None:
                return json.dumps({'data': self.t_arr[url]})
        except AttributeError:
            self.t_arr = {}
        r  = requests.get(url)
        data = r.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data,"html.parser")
        table = soup.find('div',{'id':'SMS'})
        table2 = table.find('table',{'class':'table'})
        print(table2)
        s=""
        detailtext = table2.findAll('div',{'class':'detailtext'})


        for det in detailtext:
            details_array.append(det.text)

        smalldetails = table2.findAll('div',{'style':'padding-top:5px'})


        price_cells = table.findAll('td', {'class': 'pricecell'})
        for price_cell in price_cells:
            price_cell_array.append(price_cell.text)

        for i in range(len(details_array)):
            d_arr = {}
            d_arr['detail']=details_array[i]
            tempnew = price_cell_array[i].split('\n')
            d_arr['price'] = tempnew[1]
            d_arr['validity'] = tempnew[3]
            # global list
            lst.append(d_arr)
        self.t_arr[url] = lst
        return json.dumps({'data': self.t_arr[url]})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ''' Setting up the Server with Specified Configuration'''

    cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0',})
    cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_port': int(os.environ.get('PORT', '5000')),})

cherrypy.quickstart(Server())
```

The problem is that, whenever I start my server the first default function or first called function executes, but if I try to call another function, it shows old values of previously called function.

For ex:- the code has 2 function `recharge_list` & `sms_list` . Now if I start the server by `recharge_list` then I have to restart the server to call the `sms_list` the already running server does not serve the newly called function.

What should be added in the script to make it run ?

I accept that this is a silly question, but I do not know how to get this fixed.